# Is it possible to have an automatic datestamp in Google Spreadsheet for cells that have *previously been filled out*?

Tags: google-sheets, datestamp

That is, I have information in column B, and I'd like a datestamp in column C noting when column B was filled out.  I see a bunch of onEdit scripts, but I'd like it to be retroactive--those cells have already been filled out.  Is that possible?  Does Google Spreadsheets store that information and is it accessible?

Comment: If you have a very small number of items to get the date of, you could search through the stored revisions manually. No API for that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe it is. As you mention, there are ways to get the timestamp going forward, but the information as to when a cell was filled out is not retroactively available.

The [API doucmentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) provides an `updated` field on `List` and `Cells` feeds, but that is a sheet-level property. The returned cell data does not contain any other information regarding the date, so the (unfortunate) answer is that you will likely only be able to get that level of information going forward.

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @user1781552 No problem - sorry it wasn't a more positive answer, but at least you'll be able to get it going forward :)